# Probability distributions

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let $X$ be a Chi-square random variable with $p$ degrees-of-freedom. Let $Y$ be a real Gaussian random variable with 0 mean and variance $\sigma^2$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Can we know what the following random variable follows ?

\begin{equation}
Z = \frac{XY}{aY^2 - bX}
\end{equation}
where a,b are strictly positive.

P.S: A hint would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"Hints" and a simulation, certainly not an answer.

$aY^2$ is a multiple of a chi-squared distribution.
The negative sign in the denominator means that the
denominator can be near 0, possibly with high
probability depending on $a, b,$ and $\sigma.$
So this is potentially an extremely heavy-tailed distribution.

Also the numerator is bound to be near 0 with high
probability, so for many parameter choices the
distribution will be concentrated near 0.

```
 m = 10^6;  x = rchisq(m, 3);  y = rnorm(m, 0, 5)
 a = 10;  b = 1;  z = x*y/(a*y^2 - b*x)
 summary(z)
      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
 -151700.0      -0.1       0.0       1.0       0.1 1259000.0
```

I would show a histogram, but it's just a spike near 0 and
too sparse for bars to show over the rest of its large range.

Is this just a messy exercise, or does it arise from a practical
problem?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the probability density function of the random variable in question:
\begin{eqnarray}
\rho(z) := C_{p,\sigma} \left\{
\begin{array}{rr}
\int\limits_{-b z}^\infty \left( \frac{z a y^2}{y+b z}\right)^{p/2-1} \frac{a |y|^3}{(y+b z)^2} \exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2 \sigma^2} \frac{(y+b z+a \sigma^2 z)}{(y+b z)}  \right) dy & \mbox{if $z\ge 0$}\\
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{-b z} \left( \frac{z a y^2}{y+b z}\right)^{p/2-1} \frac{a |y|^3}{(y+b z)^2} \exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2 \sigma^2} \frac{(y+b z+a \sigma^2 z)}{(y+b z)}  \right) dy & \mbox{if $z< 0$}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}
where $C_{p,\sigma}:= 1/(2^{p/2-1}\cdot\Gamma(p/2))\cdot 1/\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}$.

Below I also plot the pdfs  for $\sigma=1$ and $p=7$ and for $a=1,\cdots 4$ and $b=1,\cdots,4$ . Here the rows correspond to a fixed values of $a$ and the columns to a fixed value of $b$.
[image]